# Unable to load css in wordpress 3.6

Tags: wordpress

We are currently developing a `wordpress plugin`. But Its working fine in older version of wordpress but CSS is not being loaded in `wordpress 3.6`

For loading css we are using code :

```
global $wp_query;   
    $posts = $wp_query->posts;
    $pattern = get_shortcode_regex();

    foreach ($posts as $post)
    {
        if ( preg_match_all( '/'. $pattern .'/s', $post->post_content, $matches ) && array_key_exists( 2, $matches ) && in_array( 'MYSHORCODE', $matches[2] ) )
        {
            wp_enqueue_style('ap-bootstrap-css',plugins_url('menu-pages/bootstrap-assets/css/bootstrap-appointpress.css', __FILE__));
            wp_enqueue_script('ap-jquery.min.js',plugins_url('menu-pages/bootstrap-assets/js/jquery.min.js', __FILE__));
            wp_register_style('ap-bootstrapoverlay-css',plugins_url('overlay.css', __FILE__));
            wp_enqueue_style('ap-bootstrapoverlay-css');
        }    
    }
```

How can I resolve this problem ?

**Edit**

I am getting this problem only if I use this shortcode in only sidebar or footer

Comment: Are you loading the plugin early enough in the Wordpress initialization process? For instance, using the code `add_action("init", "myplugin");` If you load the plugin with a hook too late in the process, CSS might well get missed.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT loop through posts to load CSS and JS, yet alone all posts. This code will crash sites.

With out seeing the rest of the code, it looks like your enqueing wrong also.

In your wp-config.php turn on WP_DEBUG

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```